# Real time update for fans page

Tags: facebook, real-time, facebook-page

Is that possible to get realtime update for specific fan page?

I can get from user as long as it is allowed my apps. But how about fans?

Can send me some related documentation. If cannot, any optional I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Page and an App.
Then the Page adds that App as a tab.
Then you subscribe to Realtime-Updates for pages (instead of user) to get them.

To create an App: `see FB documentation`

To create a page: 
    `www.facebook.com/pages/create.php`

To add an App as a tab to a Page:

`www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages=1&page=YOUR_PAGE_ID`

To subscribe to an RTU for a page:

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/subscriptions?access_token=APP_ACC_TOKEN&object=page&fields=picture......`
```

Then FB will call your URL_CALLBACK anytime some page (that added you as a tab) has a change on one of the requested fields.

PS: I'm trying to subscribe to RTU for feed changes in the page, however according to the documentation is only possible to subscribe to picture  :( If someone founds how to solve that, please let me know.

See:

```
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

developers.facebook.comdocs/reference/api/realtime/

developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question which was: "how to track a fan updates", not "how to track the updates of someone who has installed your app"