# Making Facebook Application in Sandbox mode Accessible to Company Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I have a certain scenario that might be obscure but in any event here it is:

1) My overall objective is to stream Facebook updates for my company's Facebook page to Hadoop
2) I know how to do this for my FB page:
   a)  Requires a FB app
   b)  A FB Realtime subscription
   c)  A callback URL to a page that receives the GET/POST
   d)  A Flume HttpSource to receive the Http Post from FB

All of this has been done successfully  for my personal FB page.  The challenge is that I would like my company's page to add the App so that I can stream updates from their page to my company's Hadoop environment.  My marketing department would like to capture interactions with the page followers for sentiment analysis.  Finally I would like to do so with my FB app in sandbox mode.

Is it possible to have a FB app in sandbox mode and still have it visible to my company's FB page so that the page admin can go in and add the app that I created and is still in sandbox mode?

I tried adding the company as a test user and not surprisingly that attempt failed.  Is there a proxy user for my company's page that I can setup as a test user?

Comment: I think I found an answer to my question here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account.  At least the question I asked has already been posted.   I will examine this posting in more detail and if I get things working, I'll the resolution.

Comment: Another update - I found the resolution in this posting here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351924/real-time-update-for-fans-page